# How to insert a element inside a child div of a cloned html object?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="parent main">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Some Text...</p>
    <p>Some more...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group dynamic-stuff">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

I want to clone the `.parent` div and append a element inside `.child` div and then append the cloned html before `.dynamic-stuff`.

As resulting the following:

```
<div class="parent main">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Some Text...</p>
    <p>Some more...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent main">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Some Text...</p>
    <p>Some more...</p>
    <p>Dynamically Added Element..</p> //This is what I want to insert...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group dynamic-stuff">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

I have tried like this

```
$('.add_more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.main').first().clone().children().append('<p>Dynamically Added Element..</p>').insertBefore('.dynamic-stuff').show();
});
```

But this code only add `.child` div not full parent.

Comment: Show us what you have tried as of now?

Comment: Please post the jQuery that you tried which didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.clone()` to clone the parent, then use `.append()` on its `children()` to add the a line, and finally `insertBefore()` to insert it where you want:

```js
$('.add_more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var copy = $(".parent").clone();
  copy.children().append("<p>Dynamically Added Element..</p>")
  copy.insertBefore(".dynamic-stuff");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent main">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Some Text...</p>
    <p>Some more...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group dynamic-stuff">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. This only copy the inner child div, but I want including parent one... i.e, .html() return innerHtml

Answer (score 0):

you can use append method in jquery..

use

> $(".child").append ("< tag > Dynamically Added Element..< /tag >")

Answer (score 0):

you can use selector $('.main:first') instead of $('.main').first()